# JSF - f:ajax execute does not update the backing property of bean

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, execute

I have two components, one commandButton and a selectOneListbox.

I need to update the value of the backing property binded to selectOneListBox after I click on the commandButton.

Both components are inside the same `<h:form>`.
The backing Bean is a Named/SessionScoped bean.

Here is the part of my page where the components are defined:

Button:

```
    <h:commandButton formnovalidate="formnovalidate" title="Select Variable" 
                     type="button" styleClass="button_green close_window" 
                     tabindex="2" id="btnSelectVar" value="Confirm">
         <f:ajax execute="lstVarSelected" event="click" 
                 listener="#{systemOptionsControl.updateText}" onevent="updateParent"/>
    </h:commandButton>


SelectOneListBox: (selectedVariable is a String and variables is a List of String)


    <h:selectOneListbox id="lstVarSelected" name="lstVarSelected" 
                        tabindex="1" value="#{systemOptionsControl.selectedVariable}" >
        <f:selectItems value="#{systemOptionsControl.variables}"/>
    </h:selectOneListbox>
```

After I click on button, I need to get the backing propert of the oneListBox, but JSF isnt calling the set method on backing bean. Then, when I try to get the value on my updateText method, i got a NullPointerException.

I've trie a lot of solutions and none worked, anyone can give any ideas?

Here is the xhtml:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" >
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:escriba="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components/escriba"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" lang="pt-br" class="no-js">
    <body>
        <h:head>
            <h:outputScript name="jsf.js" library="javax.faces"/>
            <script language="javascript">
                function callParentButton(data) {
                    //Verifica o status da execução do ajax. 
                    var status = data.status;
                    //alert(status);
                    switch(status)
                    {
                        case 'begin':
                            break; 
                        case 'complete':
                            //Gets the name of parent button
                            var a = #{systemOptionsControl.idBtnAtualizarTextAreas}; 
                            //Calls the click.
                            var btn = document.getElementById(a.valueOf().name);
                            btn.click();
                            break;
                        } 
                    }
            </script>
        </h:head>
        <h:form prependId="false" id="frmVariables">
            <section class="box_padrao">
                <header id="box_padrao_header">
                    <h1>System Options</h1>            
                    <div id="actions_menu">
                        <h:commandButton type="button" title="Select Variable" styleClass="button_green" tabindex="2" 
                                         id="btnConfirmar" value="Confirm">
                            <f:ajax execute="lstVariables" event="click" listener="systemOptionsControl.updateText" onevent="callParentButton"/>
                        </h:commandButton>
                        <button type="button" title="Cancel" class="button_red close_window" tabindex="3" id="btnCancelar" name="btnCancel">Cancel</button>
                    </div> 
                </header>
                <div class="box_padrao_content">
                    <div class="grid_100">
                        <h2 class="legend">» Variables List </h2>   
                        <fieldset class="fieldset">
                            <div class="grid_100">
                                <h:selectOneListbox id="lstVariables" name="lstVariables" tabindex="1" value="#{systemOptionsControl.selectedVariable}" >
                                    <f:selectItems value="#{systemOptionsControl.variables}"/>
                                </h:selectOneListbox>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>      
                </div>
            </section>
        </h:form> 
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is the Bean:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package br.com.xxx.rodrigoms.control;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

/**
 *
 * @author rodrigos
 */
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class SystemOptionsControl{    

    private String selectedVariable;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {
        //non-matter code
    }

    //<editor-fold desc="GETS/SETS">
    public String getIdBtnAtualizarTextAreas(){
        return "btnUpdateTextAreas";
    }

    public String getSelectedVariable() {
        return selectedVariable;
    }

    public void setSelectedVariable(String selectedVariable) {
        this.selectedVariable = selectedVariable;
    }

    public List<String> getVariables() {
        List<String> ret = new ArrayList<>();
        //just simulating
        ret.add("1");
        ret.add("2");
        ret.add("3");
        ret.add("4");
        return ret;
    }

    //</editor-fold>

    //<editor-fold desc="Other methods">
    public void updateText(){
        //I get the NullPointerException right on next line
        String variavelAInserir = "<".concat(this.selectedVariable).concat(">");,

        /*
        code do other suffs
        */
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    }
```

Sorry about any language errors, was need change some names because its a "job" for a company.

Comment: What are you doing at listener method? Why is your commandButton type is button? What the hell is formnovalidate doing there?

Comment: Are th ebutton and the listbox placed in the same `<h:form>`? For the remainder, carefully go through the points mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked/2120183#2120183

Comment: formnovalidate was one of my tries to make it work :(

@BalusC: Yes they are. I readed this post before and didnt found any issue related to that. I can provide the full webpage if you want.

Comment: Just the smallest possible snippet which fits in `<h:body>` and reproduces the problem for us (and you!) when copypasting to a completely blank template is sufficient. We'll assume a completely empty `<h:head>`. The smallest possible bean example, including necessary imports, would also be helpful.

Comment: Okay I will try it, im stucked for hours on this problem. please wait.

Comment: @BalusC here are the code.

Comment: That's quite a lot of noise in the code. Is for example that JS code and the `<section>`, `<fieldset>`, `<h2>`, `class="legend"`, etc..etc.. absolutely necessary in order to reproduce the concrete problem? In other words, the problem disappears when you remove them? If not, just keep them out! :)

Comment: This code is not really carefully prepared. Aside from the code noise, it contains a syntax error in Java method and missing `#{}` in `<f:ajax listener>`. After fixing that, it works fine (it prints the desired selected value), however thereafter a JS error occurred because `#{systemOptionsControl.idBtnAtualizarTextAreas}` returned a string value which doesn't represent a JS variable at all. So the page dies and the second and subsequent clicks will all fail.

Comment: In any way, to exclude bad CDI configuration from the cause, what if you try JSF's own bean management annotations from `javax.faces.bean` package instead?

Comment: yeah, i forgot to put the listener when i was editing the code to paste here... im almost recording a video of the situation and sending it to you, what do you think?

Comment: This page is opened through Javascript, its a lightbox-window opened from another page. I believe that this could be causing the issue.

The strange behavior happens when i click on the button with f:ajax, instead it executes the setSelectedVariable, it is calling the getVariables again, and it never calls the set :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, I solved using the binding property.

After I bound a inputTextArea in my bean. I was able to get the selectedValue in my listener method.

The reason for the execute not "really" execute the set method before the execution of the listener i didnt discover yet.

Anyway, thank you two guys for the great help :) This was my first time asking in stackoverflow and you two were very prestative :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide enough info about your backing bean or xhtml page.
And even the part you provided contains too much invalid syntax so i decided to do a example.

Here it is for you.

**SystemOptionsControl.java**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.model.SelectItem;


@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class SystemOptionsControl {

    private Integer selectedVariable;
    private List<SelectItem> variables = Arrays.asList(new SelectItem(1),
                                                       new SelectItem(2),
                                                       new SelectItem(3));

    public void updateText(){
        System.out.print("updateText method invoked");
        System.out.print("Selected Value " + selectedVariable);        
    }

    public Integer getSelectedVariable() {
        return selectedVariable;
    }

    public void setSelectedVariable(Integer selectedVariable) {
        this.selectedVariable = selectedVariable;
    }

    public List<SelectItem> getVariables() {
        return variables;
    }

    public void setVariables(List<SelectItem> variables) {
        this.variables = variables;
    }
}
```

**Page.xhtml**

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

    <h:head>
        <title>Title</title>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>

        <h:form prependId="false">

            <h:commandButton type="button" id="btnSelectVar" value="Confirm">
                <f:ajax execute="lstVarSelected" event="click" listener="#{systemOptionsControl.updateText}" />
            </h:commandButton>


            <h:selectOneListbox id="lstVarSelected" value="#{systemOptionsControl.selectedVariable}" >
                <f:selectItems value="#{systemOptionsControl.variables}"/>
            </h:selectOneListbox>

        </h:form>

    </h:body>

</html>
```

Comment: This code is quite equals as mine. The only difference between our "codes" is that im using a List<String> instead a list of SelectItem. I will try to change this now.

Comment: Even using a List of SelectItems the 'selSelectedVariable' was not called. :(

Comment: The code above just works. Use it. Modify it step by step until it is broken. Post what breaks your code.